# mysql - Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

Getting error "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias" when running the following query through phpMyAdmin:

```html
SELECT 
    `free_from`, `free_until`
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        a.end AS `free_from`,
        (SELECT MIN(c.start) FROM bookings c WHERE c.start>a.end) as `free_until`
    FROM bookings a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM bookings b
        WHERE b.start BETWEEN a.end AND a.end + INTERVAL 30 Minute
    ) 
    AND a.end BETWEEN '2012-11-16 09:00:00' AND '2012-11-16 22:00:00' 
)
```

Can you please help me in this regard?

Comment: Your outer subquery doesn't have an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that your outer query needs an alias.  But, you don't need a subquery at all for this logic.  And, because MySQL tends to materialize subqueries, this improves performance:

```
SELECT a.end AS `free_from`,
       (SELECT MIN(c.start)
        FROM bookings c
        WHERE c.start > a.end
       ) as `free_until`    
FROM bookings a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM bookings b
                  WHERE b.start BETWEEN a.end AND a.end + INTERVAL 30 Minute
                 ) AND
      a.end BETWEEN '2012-11-16 09:00:00' AND '2012-11-16 22:00:00';
```